# Creating a pointer to a widget(wxTextCtrl) in a function

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I've trying to get a pointer to a widget (in the code it's named *text*). But at least I've got only this

> error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ostream::basic_ostream(wxWindow*)'

my code:
**gui.h**

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

class wxWCK : public wxFrame
{
public:
    wxWCK(const wxString& title);

    void OnClickCon(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnClickSta(wxCommandEvent& event);

private:
    wxButton *connect;
    wxButton *start;
    wxTextCtrl *text;
};

const int ID_CON = 100;
const int ID_STA = 101;
const int ID_MF0 = 102;
const int ID_TEX = 103;

void Connect();
void Start();
```

and **gui.cpp**
    #include "gui.h"

```
wxWCK::wxWCK(const wxString& title)
    : wxFrame(NULL, ID_MF0, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(400,300))
{
    wxPanel *panel = new wxPanel(this, -1);

    wxBoxSizer *vbox  = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    wxBoxSizer *hbox1 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxBoxSizer *hbox2 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);   

    //Outputwidget
    text = new wxTextCtrl(panel, ID_TEX, _T(""), 
        wxPoint(-1, -1), wxSize(1000, 1000), wxTE_MULTILINE);

    //redirecting stream to the outputwidget
    //std::ostream stream(text);    
    stream << "Hello" << std::endl;

    connect = new wxButton(panel, ID_CON, _T("Connect"));
    start   = new wxButton(panel, ID_STA, _T("Start"));

    hbox1->Add(text);
    hbox2->Add(connect);
    hbox2->Add(start);

    vbox->Add(hbox1, 1, wxEXPAND);
    vbox->Add(hbox2, 0, wxALIGN_LEFT | wxRIGHT | wxBOTTOM, 10);

    panel->SetSizer(vbox);

    Connect(ID_CON, wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,
        wxCommandEventHandler(wxWCK::OnClickCon));
    //Connect(ID_STA, wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED,
    //  wxCommandEventHandler(wxWCK::OnClickSta));
}

void wxWCK::OnClickCon(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{   void Connect(); }

void wxWCK::OnClickSta(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{   void Start();   }

void Connect()
{
    //Try to get a pointer to 'text'
    std::ostream stream(wxWindow::FindWindowById(ID_TEX));  
    stream << "Connected" << std::endl;
}
/*
void Start()
{
    //Try to get a pointer to 'text'
    std::ostream stream(wxWindow::FindWindowById(ID_TEX));  
    stream << "Started" << std::endl;
}
*/
```

I hope somebody can help me. A other solution can be to get the *stream* as global. But when I try to get the stream-declaration in the header, he says he dont know any *text* so I move the text-declaration outside the class and I got a muliple declaration error... I think, because I include the *gui.h* in gui.cpp and main.h .
-Casisto

edit:
I changed the the function to:

```
void Connect()
{
    //Try to get a pointer to 'text'
    std::ostream stream((wxTextCtrl*) wxWindow::FindWindowById(ID_TEX));
    stream << "Connected" << std::endl;
}
```

Now I don't get a error or a warning, but when I click on "Connect"-Button, the wxTextCtrl get no "Input" (I mean, there is only "Hello" in there)

Comment: `std::ostream stream(wxWindow::FindWindowById(ID_TEX));` you probably wanted to call s.th. like `GetText()` there, to pass it to a `std::ofstream`. You cannot create an instance of `std::ostream`, it's an abstract class.

Comment: ok, can you please loose some other word? I don't know waht you try to advice me.

Comment: The closest words I can drop here: [`wxTextCtrl::GetLineText()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_text_ctrl.html#aff9142f8741e365099e3ac87abb1726e), [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream), or did you mean [wxTextCtrl and C++ Streams](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_text_ctrl.html) section from the docs?

Comment: I mean the last one, wxtextCtrl and C++.

Comment: Your question now has nothing in common with the original one. You should probably create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial error must have been from the old code of `Connect()` because `wxWindow::FindWindowById()` returns a `wxWindow*`.

First thing to try: change `wxWCK::OnClickCon()` to `{ (*text) << "Connected\n"; }`. This should just work.

Next, if you really need that `void Connect()`, try again without creating the `std::ostream` (you don't really need it); something like `{ (*(wxTextCtrl*)wxWindow::FindWindowById(ID_TEX)) << "Connected\n"; }`.
However, this might still not work, so make `ID_CON = wxID_HIGHEST + 1`, `ID_STA = wxID_HIGHEST + 2` etc and try again. IIRC I've seen cases where ids with low values caused curious behaviour.

Comment: Hi,
when I use your codeline, I get the
       error: invalid operands of types 'wxTextCtrl*' and 'const char [11]' to binary 'operator<<'
And, I think I should use the std::stream, this is only a example, because the hole function of connect is very complex and delivered me back a string. The higher ID's dont help me, the error is still there.

Comment: doh, of course it errors out.
I've changed the code snippets to use the reference with operator<<(), so `*text` rather than `text`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message doesn't fit the code you show, in it `text` is a `wxTextCtrl`, which derives from `std::streambuf` and so can be used to construct an associated `std::ostream`, and not a `wxWindow`.

IOW your code should work as shown, you must be not showing us everything.

Comment: Hi, but the code is now (after editing) running, but nothing happens if I use a button. Some idea why?